# Is using a ja3 hash worth it?

Tags: ids

I've been reading about `ja3` and `ja3s` hashes, and although it certainly is a way to address suspicious traffic detection in encrypted traffic it still is, at least in my opinion, a static approach. It does not much differ from the "traditional" deep-packet-inspection signature-based approach. We still maintain a database of malicious `ja3` hashes (same as signatures) and `ja3` hashes can overlap (so they still introduce false positives).

[JA3 gathers the decimal values of the bytes for the following fields in the Client Hello packet](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3) `SSLVersion,Cipher,SSLExtension,EllipticCurve,EllipticCurvePointFormat`, so are there any reasons why an attacker could not or even would not change those values (even for a known malicious application) to look like a Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

If the hash is only used by itself to distinguish between malicious and non-malicious applications then it is probably not very effective since as you've said already hashes from various applications are overlapping which means that one gets either false positives or false negatives.

But the hash might be used in context with other features, like the domain name (from SNI), the behavior of the traffic flow (packet sizes, timing), other hashes usually used (i.e. something emulating the fingerprint of Chrome will stand out if the user is usually using Firefox) etc. Insofar it might be a useful feature in some anomaly detection system which is looking for traffic which does not match the usual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In general security systems, in this case NIDS, that detect things needs to deals with false positive and negatives. JA3 is a new technique that allows NIDS (snort, suricata, aiengine and others) to detect malware before they send the HTTP exploit. Of course if somebody design a malware that use the same settings as chrome or firefox then the signature will be the same. The combination of the SNI + the CA name + the JA3 can give you good results in terms of reducing the false positives. You could ask the guys of JA3 if they have a deep document on the real numbers of FP/FN in order to see the effectiveness of the method.